# User Input command line options for service installer

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, service, command-line, installation

## Background

This is my first time using a setup project, let alone doing one to install a service. Things have been progressing fairly well until I reached the point that I wanted to get user input. So far I've managed to answer all my questions based on these posts:

Creating a Setup project:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.80).aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nikhilsi/archive/2011/06/13/how-to-create-a-windows-service-in-the-component-designer.aspx

User Interface in the Setup project:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9cdb5eda(VS.71).aspx

I've created a form to accept two inputs from the user, both text inputs.

(**optional**) I'd like one to be a file chooser, and the other to be validated as an int. However, it is not a deal-breaker if they are simple text boxes.

## Question

My question is around taking the input from the user in the installer (via the text boxes) and setting them as the command line options for the installed service. In other words, if the user inputs "AAAA" into text box 1, and "1234" into text box 2, how do I install the service to launch with the following command line:

```
/OptionA "AAAA" /OptionB 1234
```